# patchMapping partial modification with springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am a beginner in springboot, I followed a tutorial but the person does not explain for patchmapping. I can't update the modified data. The only solution I found is to use if and else to see if the field is modified or not. Who could explain to me please.

userModel

```
public class User extends AbstractEntity{

    private String civility;

    private String lastname;

    private String firstname;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String password;

    private String phone;

    private String birth_day;

}
```

userDto

```
public class UserDto {

    private Integer id;
    private String civility;
    private String lastname;
    private String firstname;
    private String birth_day;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String phone;


    public static UserDto fromEntity(User user) {
        return UserDto.builder()
                .id(user.getId())
                .civility(user.getCivility())
                .lastname(user.getLastname())
                .firstname(user.getFirstname())
                .birth_day(user.getBirth_day())
                .email(user.getEmail())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .phone(user.getPhone())
                .build();
    }

    public static User toEntity(UserDto user) {
        return User.builder()
                .id(user.getId())
                .civility(user.getCivility())
                .lastname(user.getLastname())
                .firstname(user.getFirstname())
                .birth_day(user.getBirth_day())
                .email(user.getEmail())
                .password(user.getPassword())
                .phone(user.getPhone())
                .build();
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

userServiceImpl

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public Integer updateByid(Integer id, UserDto dto) {
        User user2 = userRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new EntityNotFoundException("Aucun utilisateur n'a été trouvé avec l'ID fourni :" + id));
        if (dto.getEmail() == null ) {
            user2.setEmail(user2.getEmail());
        } else {
            user2.setEmail(dto.getEmail());
        }
        user2.setPassword(dto.getPassword());
        userRepository.save(user2);
        return user2.getId();
    }
}
```

userService

```
public interface UserService extends AbstractService<UserDto> {

}
```

userController

```
public class UserController {

    private final UserService service;

    @PatchMapping("/update/{user-id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> updateAccount(
            @PathVariable("user-id") Integer userId,
            @RequestBody UserDto user
    ) {
        System.out.println(user);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.updateByid(userId,user));
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want to understand? I think code you added in self explanatory

Comment: How can I do as on the documentation instead of using the if . https://www.baeldung.com/http-put-patch-difference-spring  
I find this method much cleaner : ```@RequestMapping(value = "/heavyresource/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PATCH, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> partialUpdateGeneric(
  @RequestBody Map<String, Object> updates,
  @PathVariable("id") String id) {
    
    heavyResourceRepository.save(updates, id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("resource updated");
} ```